# Same code doesn't works on port different from 80

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have two environment on the same machine both using apache. One is for test puropuse, the other is for demo. By the way the problem is that the same code (created following http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) works only on the environment  running on port 80. How can I deploy the facebook-like button on non non standard ports?
Two months ago it works on both environment. Maybe facebook api changes something?

Any help is appreciate

Thanks in advance.
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you specify your og:url and other tags with the full URL including port number?

Comment: No it doesn't works. Port is also specified in site url and canvas url (https://developers.facebook.com/apps). What happens is that when you click send button, login is prompted and once credentials are entered flyout windows doesn't appears and like button remains disabled.